# Upload image file to a user profile in Laravel 5.2

Tags: forms, laravel, request

I've read tones of post and I can't find the way to solve my problem. I'm not getting any error but when I **dd($avatar = $request->file('avatar'));** I recive a null and I can't understand why.

**My form**

```
   {!! Form::model($usuario, ['method' => 'POST', 'action' => [ 'UsersController@updateAvatar',  $usuario->id ] ]) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('avatar', 'Sube un nuevo avatar:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('avatar') !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Actualizar avatar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**The controller**

```
public function updateAvatar (Request $request, $id)
{

    dd($avatar = $request->file('avatar'));

    if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
    {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
        $usuario = User::findOrFail($id);
        $usuario->avatar = $filename;
        $usuario->save();
    }

    return redirect('usuarios/' . $id);
}
```

**In the config/app**
I added Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class, and'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class

I updated composer file and in the json file I can see the updated file.

**I don't understand why I'm getting a null here**

```
dd($avatar = $request->file('avatar'));
```

I any one can help me I will apreciate :)
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution if anyone is having the same problem. You must add **'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"** in the form as an attribute.

The form should look like here:

```
 {!! Form::model($usuario, ['method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data" , 'action' => [ 'UsersController@updateAvatar',  $usuario->id ] ]) !!}
```

Now I recive data when I execute the dd() and I can upload my the images :)